# Android version updates for Motorola and Nexus phones

Tags: updates, google, moto-x, 5.0-lollipop

How long will Motorola and Google provide Android updates to their models Moto X(2013) and Nexus 5? Is there a limit or a deadline to these updates rolling in?
Google has said that the newer versions will be able to run even on low-end smartphones, so this means that the updates should come for at least to years to these mid-range phones but is there any confirmation to that?

Answer (score 0):

Motorolla has already started rolling out lollipop updates for Moto X(2nd gen) and Moto G(2nd gen). Nexus updates will be coming soon as well. Moto X (2013) is going to get an update, but it might be 1-2 months down the lane.